# Python Flask How to set up option between text box and upload file functionality?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am working to get a Flask app to either read text from a text box or a file upload function that I have set up in a form.

[image: My rendered entry form]
The underlying code is working well with either option, independently, but I can't tie up the "switch between" ware.

How do I incorporate a 'case' option. That is:
1. If the file upload option is selected, the app uploads and reads/processes text from the file 
2. else the app uploads text from the text box;
3. If neither file has been uploaded and nor text box is popultaed, the app exists with an error message.

*Input from text box*

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 2 * 1024 * 1024

@app.route('/')
def myform():
    return render_template("get_input.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']
....
```

*Text from upload file*

```
file = request.files['file']
f = secure_filename(file.filename)
text=f.read()
....continue with processing
```

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have **2 distinct forms** on your page a simple option would be to **add a hidden value to each form:**

```
<! -- first form -->
<input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="text_entry_form">
...
<! -- second form -->
<input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="file_upload_form">
```

Then, within your flask function you can differentiate between which form was submitted using the **form_name** value:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    if request.form['form_name'] === 'text_entry_form':
        # code to process textarea data
    else:
        # code to process file upload data
```

**Alternatively**, you could post the forms to different Flask endpoints, or you could package it all in one endpoint & view function with a [**P/R/G Pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533663/how-to-rewrite-this-flask-view-function-to-follow-the-post-redirect-get-pattern/41535663#41535663).

Rather than using [**request.form**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.form) directly, you should use the [**MultiDict get()**](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) method, like this:

```
text = request.form.get('text')  # returns None if not in the request
if text:
    # process text
```

Comment: Appreciate your insights, many thanks. In the second solution that you have outlined, how to make `text = request.form.get('text')` a common endpoint if the file upload part of the form has to first upload the file and then read (in two steps). My guess, and please educate me, was that the clic on upload button should initiate the following sequence: `file = request.files['file']
f = secure_filename(file.filename)
text=f.read()'

Comment: I believe [**werkzeug.secure_filename**](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename) returns **string** and only needs to be used if you want to save the file somewhere. if you don't want to save you should be able to do: `if 'file' in request.files:` then `file = request.files['file']` then `file.read()` [**Flask upload Docs**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/#uploading-files)

Comment: Thanks very much. the markup looks like: `<form input type="hidden" name="myform" value="text_entry_form" method="post">
  <textarea name="text"  rows="4" cols="150"></textarea><br>
 <input type="submit" name="myform" value="Send">
 
 </form>
<h2>Or upload a text file, max value (this version) is 2MB:</h2>

<form input type="hidden" name="myform" value="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name= "file">
         <input type=submit  name="myform" value=Upload >
    </form>` This is working perfectly, gets my job done.